# How would I account for non-linear refractive index effects in a nitrogen based medium?

Tags: optics, refraction, plasma-physics, non-linear-optics

I am trying to estimate the clamped intensity of a 90 fs femtosecond laser when it passes through a flow of nitrogen that is exiting a nozzle. Prior to the nozzle, the incoming nitrogen flow is heated by an electric arc that significantly raises its temperature, resulting in the flow at the nozzle exit being a plasma at thermal non-equilibrium with a population of about 99.9 % N2 and 0.1 % atomic N.

Since the clamped intensity in literature is usually calculated by performing a balance of self-focusing and defocusing due to the 'plasma' from the high peak intensity of the laser, it would involve accounting for the non-linear intensity-based refractive index of the medium.

n = n2I

While there is literature that goes over the density-dependent non-linear index (n2) for diatomic nitrogen, there isn't any readily available data that I could use to include the effect of the monoatomic nitrogen within my volume of interest.

Since my background is in Aerospace, I was curious if anyone had any suggestions of an approach I could follow to get it or some literature that I could look into. I was also wondering if I am overthinking the problem and if an assumption of a negligible contribution to non-linear refractive index change due to the extremely small atomic nitrogen concentration would be valid.

Comment: This seems like quite a demanding physical modeling problem, involving absorption and refraction in a complicated gas flow, and it's so specific that maybe it would be easier to measure than to calculate.

Comment: My feeling is that you are indeed over-thinking the problem. Typically gas jets will not have such a strong self-focusing and clamping because : 1- you want to drive the system where you only ionize a small fraction of the system (otherwise you just lose all your energy to the plasma); 2- the interaction length is short; 3- the medium is quite low-density. Only in over-driven systems (which some people exploit in special situations) you might have extremely complicated propagation effects and reshaping of your pulse.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I just did some analysis in the meantime based on some number density calculations for the nozzle exit and I found that the peak power of my femtosecond laser was two orders of magnitude lower than the critical power required for self-focusing. I was, however, curious, whether the plasma would have any defocusing effects that would counteract the geometrical focusing from a field lens. The basic idea of this analysis is kinetic modelling of the  laser interaction with the flow to quantify the evolution of the fluorescence to compare against experimental results.

Comment: Like you saw, the n2 depends on the density of the medium. Plasma effects will be the same. If your gas is very dillute, you will not see much effects (its almost like going through vacuum). All this will depend on your rayleigh range, peak intensity and gas cone. If you use UPPE for pulse modelling, all effects should be counted. In general you either consider the gas as static for pulse propagation, or instantaneous ionization for plasma evolutions.